# How to use Do and NestList combine?

Tags: programming

```
g[x_]:=((i - 1/i)*x + (1/i)*(x/2))/2;
```

I want to find the following list

```
NumberForm[NestList[g, 0.8, 20], 16];
```

But don't know how to use "Do" for the values of i= {1,2,3,4,.....} varies with each step

Help would be very welcome

Comment: Maybe `g[x_, i_] := ((i - 1/i) x + (1/i) (x/2))/2;  FoldList[g, 0.8, Range[20]]`

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)!   
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. 
Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Answer (score 2):

I assume that you want to obtain following list

```
{0.8,g[0.8 (*with i=1*)],g[g[0.8] (*with i=2*)]...}
```

One way:

```
g[x_, i_] := ((i - 1/i) x + (1/i) (x/2))/2;
FoldList[g, 0.8, Range[20]]
```

Another way, if you really want to use `NestList`

```
g2[{x_, i_}] := {((i - 1/i) x + (1/i) (x/2))/2, i + 1};
First@Transpose@NestList[g2, {0.8, 1}, 20]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Dear, but I think the sequence be look like {0.8,g[0.8 (*with i=1*)],g[g[0.8 (*with i=1)*] (*with i=2*)]...}, Is it the same one or will be different???

Comment: @Marwat yes it is the same one. I just dropped there "with i=1" in my description.